# Epimorphism from G to Z

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, epimorphisms

I've got a problem with this exercise, I'd be thankful if someone could help.
Let $G$ be a group and let $f$ be an epimorphism from $G$ to  $\mathbb{Z}$. Show that for every positive integer $n$, $G$ has a normal subgroup of index $n$ in $G$.
Hint: Define an epimorphism from G in  $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and use the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**More hint.** Let $g$ be a composition of canonical projection from $\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ and $f$. Consider the kernel of $g$.

Comment: Yes, that would be the epimorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb{Z}_n$. How can I look into the Kernel or the epimorphism without knowing anything about G?

The other thing would be that I can say $G/Ker(g)$ is isomorph to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $G/Ker(f)$ is isomorph to $\mathbb{Z}$, but I don't know how to continue from here...

Comment: @DavidMolano If $N$ is a normal group of $G$ then $|G:N|=|G/N|$. What is the cardinality of $G/N$?

Comment: It Would be the cardinal of $\frac{\mid G\mid }{\mid N\mid }$ in the case of G being finite, but this is not that case. A problem with this is that I can't use some useful theorems because G is infinite (Being f a surjective function from G to an infinite set). Should I remember another way to find the cardinal of $G/N$ if G is infinite?

Comment: @DavidMolano The equality $|G:N|=|G/N|$ holds even if $G$ and $N$ are **infinite**, since both $[G:N]$ and $G/N$ are *same* set - they are the set of equivalent class given by $N$. (However, $G/N$ is a group and $[G:N]$ is *not* a group in general.)

Comment: Yes, I wrote a thing that I wasn't trying to write. I was trying to say it would be $\frac{∣G∣}{∣N∣}$ only if G was finite. And I don't know or remember a similar theorem I can use for infinite groups.

Comment: Why you try to calculate $|G|/|N|$? It is not well-defined if both $G$ and $N$ are infinite, as you know. However, By first isomorphism theorem, $G/N$ and $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ is isomorphic where $N=\operatorname{ker}g$ so $|G/N|=n$.

Comment: Oh, what a thing I didn't see, I already had the isomorphism, I just didn't see that last thing... thanks.